# Simple class giving me unexpected values?

Tags: python

I have created a simple function to give me random characters but it's throwing in random space values when i try to run it:

```py
import string
import random

class Random:

    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
    def randomiser(self):
        st = string.printable
        s = ''
        for _ in range(self.length):  
            s+=random.choice(st)
        return s

r = Random(25)
print(r.randomiser())
```

Comment: yes but it's giving me way too many spaces

Comment: Try replacing `print(...)` with `print(repr(...))`

Comment: 6% of the characters in `string.printable` are blanks of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

whitespace is one of the characters in ASCII which is included string.printable, if you want to print all letters maybe you can try string.letters

Answer (score 0):

If you print out `string.printable`, you'll see that it contains a tab. You can check this easily with

```
print(list(string.printable))

['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~', ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r', '\x0b', '\x0c']
```

A simple way to get rid of it is just a filtered list comprehension

```
st = [c for c in string.printable if c not in {"\t"}]
```

Add any characters you want to remove into the Set. I added the tab here, but as noted in the comments, there may be others that you may want to remove as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am using sets to intersect between different characters and then using them so that you can use all different options from the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html like

'whitespace', 'ascii_lowercase', 'ascii_uppercase', 'ascii_letters', 'digits', 'hexdigits', 'octdigits', 'punctuation', 'printable',

```py
import string
import random


class Random:

    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def randomiser(self):
        no_whitespace = list(set(string.printable) - set(string.whitespace)) #intersection of sets
        random.shuffle(no_whitespace) # shuffling, not using a loop
        return ''.join(no_whitespace[:self.length]) # choosing self.length elements then converting to string 


r = Random(25)
print(r.randomiser())
```